# Как проверить активность в Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу Бота для ВК Сообщества на Python.

Есть цепочка действий и задач, которая может так неплохо нагрузить компьютер.

Т.е.:

Когда нужно, чтобы процесс работал индивидуально с каждым пользователем - создаётся новый python файл, который это всё обеспечивает, но чтобы компьютер не нагружался, если пользователь не активный, нужно сделать проверку на активность.

Т.е.:

Вот пользователь написал команду: "`Бот, тест`", создался новый индивидуальный файл, который будет работать с пользователем: Принимать/Отвечать и т.д.

Как сделать так, чтобы после открытия программы параллельно проверялось: сколько времени нет ответа?

Если время вышло - написать определённое сообщение и закрыть индивидуальную программу.

Есть какие-то методы?

Comment: Использовать базу данных

Comment: Каким образом? Создать ещё один файл для определения актива и через него записывать актив?

Comment: в принципе не очень понятно, что вам надо, но никакие файлы для индивидуальной работы не нужны точно

Comment: Ну, я остановился на таком решении, и у меня уже получилось. Код довольно работоспособный, но нужна проверка, когда было отправлено последнее сообщение

Comment: Достаточно записывать в бд айди каждого юзера и его состояние актива, если это необходимо, и отталкиваясь от этого проводить какие-то операции, в вк есть лонгпул, не нужны никакие файлы

Comment: А сделать ожидание, пока не будет выполнено действие? Ладно, попробую сейчас разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: ожидание такое делается следующим образом, ты хендлером ловишь обновления в вк. Если оно есть - действие, если нет pass